# Abbreviate a two word name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function to convert a name into initials. This function return strictly takes two words with one space in between them.

The output should be two capital letters with a dot separating them.

It should be like this:

`alex cross` => `A.C`

`jaber ali`  =>  `J.A`

Here is my solution

```js
function initialName(firstLetterFirstName, firstLetterLastName) {
    'use strict'
    let x = firstLetterFirstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    let y = firstLetterLastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    return x + '.' + y;
}

console.log(initialName('momin', 'riyadh'));  // M.R
```

Have I solved this problem with hardcoded, and my approach is right? or could it be better!

Comment: [Obligatory read about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). How would you abbreviate Jean-Claud Van Damme?

Comment: One problem can introduce more, but a solution!

Comment: @VLAZ : it's not even close to `Antoine de Saint-Exupéry`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I thought I'd start off easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use regex for that:

```js
function initialName(words) {
    'use strict'
    
    return words
        .replace(/\b(\w)\w+/g, '$1.')
        .replace(/\s/g, '')
        .replace(/\.$/, '')
        .toUpperCase();
}

console.log(initialName('momin riyadh'));  // M.R
console.log(initialName('momin riyadh ralph')); // M.R.R
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you abbreviate `Jean-Claud Van Damme`?

Comment: @Momin: In my humble opinion, there's a *shorter* [way around,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61632371/11299053) that may address inputs like that with just a slight fix

Comment: @Momin as @Yevgen said, you can simply replace `/\s/g` with `/[\s-]/g` in the second replace attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
name.split(' ').map(el => el[0]).join('.').toUpperCase()
```

In you case with multiple parts could be like this:

```
function make(...parts) {
   return parts.map(el => el[0]).join('.').toUpperCase()
}
```

Comment: I'd say `split(/[\s-]/)` would better address inputs, like `jean-claude van damme`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
    var str = "Abdul Basit";
    var str1 = "This is a car";
    console.log(getInitials(str));
    console.log(getInitials(str1));
    
    function getInitials(str) {
      var matches = str.match(/\b(\w)/g);
      return matches.join('.').toUpperCase();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, but it could be written in a one-liners:

```js
console.log(
  ['john', 'doe']
  .map(word => `${word[0].toUpperCase()}.`).join('')
)
```